# Javascript .includes() not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I am working on a function which looks through a list of table values on the page and if the column title contains any part of the `output`, it will convert the value accordingly.

```
function createLink(field, val) {

var output = {
    'ntid': 'https://internal/profile/' + val,
    'email': 'mailTo:' + val
};

var i, key, keys = Object.keys(output);
for ( i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i ) {
        key = keys[i];
  if ((field.toLowerCase()).includes(key)) {
     return '<a href="'+output[key]+'" target="_blank">'+val+'</a>';
  }
}

return val;
}
```

The issue I am running into is that IE is throwing an error on the `.includes()` line stating that "Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'".

I had a bit of trouble getting it to work as is but didn't realize `includes()` must be something that not all browsers support.

Is there something else I can use in place of this that will allow for cross browser support ?

Comment: Isn't there a polyfill in the MDN documentation?

Comment: [link to polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill)

Comment: people should upvote this question more. before myself it had 0 upvotes. when this is a really good question with a solid answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`includes` is part of the ECMAScript 2016](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control) specification, so it's not supported in IE. What you can use instead is `.indexOf(element) !== -1`

Answer (score 11):

replace:

```
if(field.toLowerCase().includes(key)) {
```

to:

```
if(field.toLowerCase().indexOf(key) > -1) {
```

Answer (score 3):

For your reference, [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility) shows which browsers support `String.prototype.includes`.

IE does not have any support. That being said, you can always polyfill it, or do as others have specified and use `String.prototype.indexOf`.

Polyfill src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof start !== 'number') {
      start = 0;
    }

    if (start + search.length > this.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    }
  };
}
```